# Resizing an ExpandItem gets jumpy

Tags: java, swt

I have a sash that triggers a resize of a StyledText and the height of the ExpandItem in which it lives.  It gets "jumpy".  In other words, the StyledText tends to expand to the desired size and then reverts back to its original size as it is being resized.  In the end everything lands in the right spot, but it's an ugly transition.

What can I change in the following code to get rid of the "jumpiness"?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
    shell.setSize(400, 400);

    //Create the expand bar
    ExpandBar expandBar1=new ExpandBar(shell,SWT.None);

    //Create the first expand item.
    final ExpandItem expandItem1=new ExpandItem(expandBar1,SWT.None);
    final Composite composite=new Composite(expandBar1,SWT.NONE);
    final RowLayout layout=new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL);
    composite.setLayout(layout);
    expandItem1.setControl(composite);
    expandItem1.setHeight(100);

    //Add text
    final StyledText one=new StyledText(composite,SWT.BORDER|SWT.MULTI|SWT.WRAP|SWT.V_SCROLL);
    one.setText("aaaa\nbbbbbb\nccccc\ndddd");

    //Add a sash
    final Sash sash1=new Sash(composite,SWT.HORIZONTAL);
    sash1.setSize(sash1.getSize().x, 10);
    sash1.addListener(SWT.Selection,new Listener(){
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            one.setSize(one.getSize().x,event.y);
            sash1.setLocation(0, event.y+5);
            expandItem1.setHeight(event.y+10);
            composite.redraw();
        }
    });

    //Create the second expand item.
    ExpandItem expandItem2=new ExpandItem(expandBar1,SWT.None);
    Composite composite2=new Composite(expandBar1,SWT.None);
    composite2.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    StyledText two=new StyledText(composite2,SWT.V_SCROLL);
    two.setText("two\nabadfae\nasdfaef\nadfef\nesfj;lef\nefsfe\nasefae\n...");
    expandItem2.setControl(composite2);
    expandItem2.setHeight(100);

    //Final junk
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Note:  Feel free to give any other tips on improving this code.  I'm new to SWT.

Comment: I tried on a RHEL6 machine as well and still saw the problem.  First, I expand the top expandItem and then drag the sash that sits between the textbox and the next expandItem.  As I am dragging, the textbox "jumpily" changes sizes.  I let go of the mouse button and everything lands where it should.

Comment: Now I exactly know what you mean and I can confirm it. I can't offer a fix right now, but I think it would help if you explain what you are trying to do with placing a Sash (which users would hardly notice) in that place?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  The idea of the sash is to resize the contents of the expand item.  When fully implemented, each expandItem will have a Table class with several rows of data (I'm using StyledText now for the proof of concept).  The user wants to compare certain rows of certain tables visually.  The idea is to allow the user to see segments of two or more tables given a limited space.  The sash in the final product will be more pronounced to the user.

Comment: Hm, I think the reason for jumpiness is the SelectionListener on the Sash widget. You should probably remove it and leave the layout management and resizing completely to SWT. It's not satisfactory but perhaps ExpandItems are just not the best container widgets for resizable items.

Comment: I'll consider that option.  Another thing I noticed that if I don't resize `expandItem1`, the resizing is smooth.  In practice, this means you can only shrink the control, but I wonder which event is causing the faulty resize hook to be called.